# Use date based calculation using case condition in SSRS report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

```
Select 
Case When @Date between '04/01/2018' and '05/31/2018' Then 0.06
     When @Date between '06/01/2018' and '06/30/2018' Then 0.07
     When @Date between '07/01/2018' and '07/31/2018' Then 0.08 
Else 0.06 End
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: i need to use this same querry in ssrs reporting services.

Comment: i tried as below but its not happening:

Comment: =round(Sum(Fields!BASE_APR_1ST.Value, "score")*
IIF(Parameters!TODATE.Value > "04/01/2018" and < "05/31/2018",0.06)

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
=round(Sum(Fields!BASE_APR_1ST.Value, "score"))*  
IIF(Parameters!TODATE.Value >= "04/01/2018" and Parameters!TODATE.Value <= "05/31/2018"  ,0.06
,IIF(Parameters!TODATE.Value >= "06/01/2018" and Parameters!TODATE.Value <= "06/30/2018"  ,0.07
,IIF(Parameters!TODATE.Value >= "07/01/2018" and Parameters!TODATE.Value <= "07/31/2018"  ,0.08,0.06)))
```

**Update:** Alternate option. Using `Switch`.

```
=round(Sum(Fields!BASE_APR_1ST.Value, "score"))* 
SWITCH(
                Parameters!Startdate.Value >= "04/01/2018" and Parameters!Startdate.Value <= "05/31/2018", 0.06,
                Parameters!Startdate.Value >= "06/01/2018" and Parameters!Startdate.Value <= "06/30/2018", 0.07,
                Parameters!Startdate.Value >= "07/01/2018" and Parameters!Startdate.Value <= "07/31/2018", 0.08,
                true, 0.06
            )
```

Comment: I would suggest using Switch instead of nested Iif

Comment: @niktrs Added Switch usage as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use custom code to realize this requirement.
Right Click Blank area of report -> "Report Properties" -> Code

```
Function GetDate(ByVal dt As DateTime) As String
    If (dt >= Date.Parse("04/01/2018") AndAlso dt <= Date.Parse("05/31/2018")) Then
        Return "0.06"
    ElseIf (dt >= Date.Parse("06/01/2018") AndAlso dt <= Date.Parse("06/30/2018")) Then
        Return "0.07"
    ElseIf (dt >= Date.Parse("07/01/2018") AndAlso dt <= Date.Parse("07/31/2018")) Then
        Return "0.08"
    Else
        Return "-"
    End If
End Function
```

And call this function in the expression of textbox like this: "=Code.GetDate(Fields!Date.Value)"

Comment: In my opinion custom code should be avoided in cases like this. You can use Iif or even better a Switch expression to achieve the same result. Also based on the requirements your function should return a decimal instead of string.